After adding context to a closed question, my question was deleted. Would greatly appreciate additional details.
A few weeks ago, I had a question that was closed.  I posted here asking why it was closed.  I was told that it was closed because it was missing context.
I saw that the details for closing the question clearly called out that it was missing context and that there was a clear criteria for context so I deleted my question and added context.
After I added context, the question is now deleted:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4926188/how-does-the-cauchy-condensation-test-prove-that-for-any-p-1-the-sum-sum
I would have been fine if anyone had provided a more detailed comment or if it was clearer what I did wrong when I attempted to add context.
I try very hard to follow all the rules on the site.  I use the site to better understand mathematical concepts and I have leveraged this site to learn more deeply on fundamental mathematical topics.
I was not clear why a question about a criteria related to the convergence of an infinite series required context.  I attempted to provide it.  I read through the details for adding context and attempted to add the details found here:
How to ask a good question.
I would appreciate if someone could explain the justification for deleting the question.  If I understand what is wrong with the question, I will avoid asking these questions in the future.
The folks who voted to the deleted the question are identified in closure.  I would appreciate if one of you could explain why you chose to delete the question rather than post a comment on what could be improved.  I would have been very glad to improve the question.
I would be very glad to understand why do you feel a question about the Cauchy Convergence Test is not appropriate to ask on MSE and why do you feel that the context that I provided is insufficient.
Thanks very much.

Briefly mentioned by one of the deleters in the CURED chatroom around the same time as your edit.

The context is probably ok now. But the question still looks like a duplicate to me. The answer to this linked question is using Cauchy condensation, after all.

Essentially so does this answer in a rather canonical version about the convergence/divergence of $p$-series.

Thanks, Jyrki.  It seems to me that if we are too strict on duplicates, then it would not make sense to allow any elementary questions on this site for they have most likely at this point been answered directly or indirectly. I was not clear on the other answer and my point in the question was further information. Are clarifications of a previous question allowed?  Is there a site guideline on this that can help me to clarify the context of the question?

I read through the link.  That is a great answer to my question.  I am fine with keeping it deleted.  I will bookmark the answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29450/convergence-of-the-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1np-for-p-1/130498#130498

I can't view the deleted question because I don't have 10K, so I can't judge this specific case.  Normally if a question meets quality standards but is a duplicate, the appropriate response is to close it as a duplicate, rather than deleting it.  That incrementally helps others who might have the same question, find it via websearch.  That said, if no one cares enough to undelete it, perhaps it's moot and not worth worrying about.
